# How to compare values present in two sets with same size

Tags: java, collections

How to compare values present in two sets with same size.

Comment: Read the docs, and try it out. After that show us how you are doing it. Then we might come up with a better way.

Comment: @pavanc, how helpful would it be to you if everyone spent only ten seconds writing an answer to your question? Couldn't you invest a little more time than that in asking it? I, for one, have no idea what you're really asking here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use iterators. and compare through iterating.
like this

```
     HashSet h1 =  new HashSet();
     HashSet h2 =  new HashSet();
     Iterator it1 = h1.iterator();

     while(it1.hasNext()){
         if(!h2.contains(it1.next()))
             // do whatever u want
            boolean notequal = true ;
     }
```

Comment: I voted down this solution because HashSet is unordered collection, means that you never know what is the order of the entries inside it. Obviously not the solution.

Comment: Caught your change a bit too late, so I can't retract my downvote. Still, `equals()` achieves the very same, I think, with much less coding.

Answer (score 7):

Heh? Is using the equals from the Set object not enough?

Comment: One would think so, so +1. However, the question is sufficiently ill-defined that maybe pavanc wants to do something different.

Comment: They could be two different Set implementations, in which case equals wouldn't work.

Comment: equals() still works in almost every case, unless you (a) use the keySet of an IdentityHashMap (who does that?) or use a SortedSet with a comparator that is inconsistent with equals(), which the javadocs specifically warn you not to do.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that both sets contain the same type of objects.
Then it depends on whether you can rely on the inherent comparison of the elements, or whether you need some other type of comparison.

The [Apache CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) has a super-sweet method called isEqualCollection

public static boolean isEqualCollection(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)

Answer (score 0):

Are the sets the same size?  Or are you looking for the same size values in both sets?

As for the comparison, what type of values are in the sets?

Comment: @Asher: There's no answer in there - so I'd have added that as a comment on the question instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Martin.  I'm still getting used to how things work here.